# How can I globally set a custom HtmlEncoder to use in all Razor pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

**I want to set a custom `HtmlEncoder` as the default `HtmlEncoder` to be used in Asp.net Core Razor pages.**

The `RazorPageBase` class does have a `HtmlEncoder` property which I can set on a single Razor page like this:

```
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Text.Unicode;
@{
    HtmlEncoder = HtmlEncoder.Create(UnicodeRanges.All);
}
```

Then the `HtmlEncoder` is used on that page.

Now the obvious thing to try is to apply this code to 'ViewStart.cshtml':

```
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Text.Unicode;
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
    HtmlEncoder = HtmlEncoder.Create(UnicodeRanges.All);
}
```

However, this does not work, it still uses the default `HtmlEncoder` (it compiles fine and it does pick up the Layout property).

This means, that to set the default `HtmlEncoder` for all pages, I have to include the code above to each and every Razor page, including each and every Partial page and of course "_Layout.cshtml".

I hope I have missed something.

**How can I specify this on a global scale so it applies to all Razor pages?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your app configuration, do the following:

```
[.NET 6 Program.cs]
builder.Services.Configure<WebEncoderOptions>(options =>
{
    options.TextEncoderSettings = new TextEncoderSettings(UnicodeRanges.All);
});
```

Or

```
[Pre-.NET 6 Startup.cs]
services.Configure<WebEncoderOptions>(options =>
{
    options.TextEncoderSettings = new TextEncoderSettings(UnicodeRanges.All);
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.